# TensorFlow object detection limiting memory and cpu usage

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow, object-detection

I manage to run tensorflow pet example from the tutorial. I decided to use the slowest model (because I want to use for my own data). However, when I start the training it gets killed after running a bit. It used all my cpus (4) and all my memory 8GB. Do you know anyway I can limit the number of CPUs to 2 and limit the amount of memory used ? If I reduce the batch size ? My batch size is already 1.

I managed to run by reducing the resize:

image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 300
        max_dimension: 612
      }

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea to reduce memory usage is to reduce the queue sizes for input data.  Specifically, in the `object_detection/protos/train.proto` file, you will see entries for `batch_queue_capacity` and `prefetch_queue_capacity` --- consider setting these fields explicitly in your config file to smaller numbers.